# Japanese movie with girl who goes boom at the end

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I am looking for a japanese(?) anime movie that I watched around 15 years ago, but it's probably much older. Unfortunately I don't remember many details.

I think that action was set in the near future. There was a girl, who was really important for some bad people (corporation maybe?). In fact I remember only the ending, in which she is plugged to some kind of computer, tells that the bad people did many bad things and she's going to destroy everything, starts the countdown, and like she said, destroys everything around in explosion. After that, from the ruins rise the good guys that survived (there was a young boy, I think) and they find their robot friend.

I'm afraid that's all I remember. I'd be really happy if anyone could help me.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Is that really a good title for your question?  I guess it could attract interest and some levity, but it isn't really very helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This might be a longshot... but it could be [*Metropolis (2001)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0293416/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2).

The basic plot surrounds a girl named Tima, who is pursued through a vast cityscape by the rulers of the futuristic city.  I base this guess by my very vague memory of the ending, in which Tima (actually a robot designed to be an all-controlling AI, but who is not actually aware of that fact) causes the city to mostly self-destruct, so she does indeed go boom.  The boy that was her friend survives and I think is attempting to salvage her.

[image].

Comment: I say a longshot mainly because my bare-minimum experience with anime and Japanese fantasy tells me that giant explosive disasters centered on a young girl is actually pretty common.

Comment: It's that movie! Thank you! I was looking for it quite long. Thanks to you I can  finally watch it again.